# MarkLogic - JSON to XML conversion - handling multiple attributes

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I have a document as below.

```
let j = {
  "PolicyInfo" :
  {
    "id" : "12345",
    "PolNum" : "TestPolicy",
    "NameInfo":
    {
      "idref":"9999",
      "Name":"TestName"
    }
  }
}
```

My requirement is to convert id (under PolicyInfo) and also idref (under NameInfo) to attributes while converting to XML. I am able to use below code to handle one attribute.

```
const JsonConfig = json.config('custom');
JsonConfig['whitespace'] = 'ignore';
JsonConfig['attribute-names'] = 'id';
json.transformFromJson(j, JsonConfig)
```

I tried below options but both of them not working.

```
JsonConfig['attribute-names'] = ['id','idref'];
JsonConfig['attribute-names'] = ('id','idref');
```

Is there a way to handle multiple attributes while converting to XML?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `Sequence.from` function:

```
JsonConfig['attribute-names'] = Sequence.from(['id', 'idref']);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.